# Why 644 permission for files?

Tags: linux, permissions

I don't want to show the website files to other users in the machine . But why it's said that 644 permission for files is okay. other user can read my file and can get many information from the code ( say PHP scripts | there are database information as well in the scripts ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule is that files served by a web service should not be writeable by the user the web service is running under. That's why the 644 or 640 permission is necessary.

If you want to restrict other users from reading your files, use the 640 permission with the group ownership set to the group under which the web service is running.